In ONOS SDN controller.. is it possible to connect a single device by using two protocols in network configuration file?
Trying below network configuration:
{
  "devices": {
    "192.168.8.220": {
       "netconf:": {
        "ip": "192.168.8.220",
        "port": 830,
        "username": "Admin",
        "password": "admin@123",
      },
     "snmp": {
        "ip": "192.168.8.220",
        "port": 162,
        "username": "Admin",
        "password": "admin@123"
      },
      "basic": {
        "name": "8.220",
        "driver": "user-netconf",
        "serial": "00009236"
      }
    }
  }
}

Requirement:
My device supports both Netconf and SNMP.
Netconf: Doesn't include LLDP yang
SNMP: Incldues LLDP
So, by using Netconf able to perform device and ports discovery.
As Netconf doesn't support LLDP, want to use SNMP for link discovery.
Queries:
Is this possible to use two protocols in single device?
When I tried it is trying to create separate device per each protocol.
If it supports, please provide valid JSON info.
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Kanth
